# Carrierwave Translation Missing on Validation File Size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave

I try this https://gist.github.com/chrisbloom7/1009861 for validate file size on carrierwave

1. I have created `lib/file_size_validator.rb`
2. I have put some transalation to file yml (wrong_size, size_too_small,size_too_big, number.human.storage_units.units.mb)
3. Put `require 'file_size_validator'` to my model
4. restart server etc...

There is nothing overlooked

but when I try to upload video with 24MB of size, i got the error :

```
I18n::MissingTranslationData in VideosController#create

translation missing: id.number.human.storage_units.units.mb

lib/file_size_validator.rb:51:in `block in validate_each'
lib/file_size_validator.rb:42:in `each'
lib/file_size_validator.rb:42:in `validate_each'
app/controllers/videos_controller.rb:67:in `create'
```

here's `id.yml` looks like :

```
id:
  errors:
    messages:
      wrong_size: "is the wrong size (should be %{file_size})"
      size_too_small: "is too small (should be at least %{file_size})"
      size_too_big: "is too big (should be at most %{file_size})
  number:
    human:  
      storage_units:
         format: "%n %u"
      units:
         byte:
           one: "Byte"
           other: "Bytes"
         kb: "KB"
         mb: "MB"
         gb: "GB"
         tb: "TB"
```

here's `video.rb`

```
require 'file_size_validator'
class video < ActiveRecord::Base
mount_uploader :file, VideoUploader
before_save :update_file_attributes, :validatefile
before_update :update_file_attributes

validates :file,
  presence: true,
  :file_size => { 
      :maximum => 20.megabytes.to_i 
    }
```

Here's `videos_controller.rb` line 67

```
@video = Video.create(params[:video])
```

Could you please help me correct my steps and my code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a nesting error in your translation file. it should be

```
id:
  errors:
    messages:
      wrong_size: "is the wrong size (should be %{file_size})"
      size_too_small: "is too small (should be at least %{file_size})"
      size_too_big: "is too big (should be at most %{file_size})
  number:
    human:  
      storage_units:
        format: "%n %u"
        units:
           byte:
             one: "Byte"
             other: "Bytes"
           kb: "KB"
           mb: "MB"
           gb: "GB"
           tb: "TB"
```